# how to get selected text from html select in asp.net code-behind?

Tags: asp.net, html

I use html Select in apsx page and bind it to data in database as dropdown:

```
<SELECT id="dd"  name="dd" runat="server" DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="Name">
```

Then in code behind, I can get the selected item value(which is mapped to ID) as:

```
myvalue = dd.value;
```

But I want to get the selected text(which is mapped to Name), not the value in code behind. How to do it?

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy towards others...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get select item name from html SELECT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924425/how-to-get-select-item-name-from-html-select)

Answer (score 6):

try this dd.Items[dd.SelectedIndex].Text

Answer (score 2):

```
myvalue = dd.SelectedText;
```

**Edit:** For a databound htmlselect you can try:

```
myvalue = dd.DataSource[dd.SelectedIndex][dd.DataTextField].ToString();
```

Comment: If doing in that way, I get error said 'SelectedText' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect'.

Comment: @KentZhou - added a new item for you to try.

Comment: `SelectedText` is not a valid property for HtmlSelect. See the other answer for unbounded HtmlSelect dropdowns