# How to get select item name from html SELECT?

Tags: asp.net, html

Use Html element SELECT in aspx page like:

```
<SELECT id="MySelection" name="MySelection" runat="server" DataValueField="ID"  DataTextField="Name"></SELECT>
```

Data is feed by setting its property DataSource:

```
MySelection.DataSource = IEnumerable collection Data
```

Suppose data is stored in table in DB like:

1. Option A
2. Option B
3. Option C
4. Option D

From `MySelection.Value`, I can get the ID value, like 1,2,3.

From `MySelection.Name`, I will get "MySelection", not the selected item name like "Option A"

How to get the selected item Name?

Comment: You should be able to get the Name by accessing the DataSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason that you aren't using the ASP.NET DropDownList?

In order to get the text from a select element you should be able to use:

```
MySelection.Items[MySelection.SelectedIndex].Text;
```

Answer (score -1):

My answer would be the same as @kevev22 but even easier.

```
MyDropDownList.Text
```

Comment: I think that he was using an actual html <select> element and not the ASP.NET DropDownList control, so this would not work.

Comment: I agree it does sound like he's using the [`HtmlSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.aspx) control instead of a `DropDownList` but `HtmlSelect` does have a [Value property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect.value.aspx), so `MySelection.Value` could be used.  There is no `Text` property for an HtmlSelect control though.

Comment: The question is, why would he use HtmlSelect if asp renders the same html markup once the page loads? The only difference being is that you have less control over html controls in the codebehind as apposed to asp controls.