# Get selected value of HTML Select dropdown

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

What is the best way to get the selected value of an `HTML Select` element? I know for ASP.net I could do something like this:

```
<select id="myDrpDown" name="myDrpDown" class="form-control" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

**C#**

```
myDrpDown.SelectedValue
```

I am able to pull the selected text using this:

```
Request.Form["myDrpDown"];
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myvalue = myDrpDown.SelectedText;
```

Or,

```
myvalue = myDrpDown.DataSource[myDrpDown.SelectedIndex][myDrpDown.DataTextField].ToString();
```

[how to get selected text from html select in asp.net code-behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378222/how-to-get-selected-text-from-html-select-in-asp-net-code-behind)